# Date range query not works in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to aws dynamodb and hit the query as shown below

```
let params = {
    TableName: tableName
};
if (from && to) {
    params.FilterExpression = 'createdOn >= :from and createdOn <= :to';
    params.ExpressionAttributeValues = { ":from": from, ":to": to }
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
        //do stuff
      }else{//do stuff}
   });  
});
```

and here is my db schema

```
 const ApplicationDataSchema = {
    TableName: "data1", //config.get('aws_tables.APPLICATIONS_DATA'),
    KeySchema: [
    { AttributeName: "id", KeyType: "HASH" },
    { AttributeName: 'createdOn', KeyType: 'RANGE' }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "S" },
    { AttributeName: 'createdOn', AttributeType: 'N' }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
  }
```

is there any need to change in schema I am not getting the correct result.
createdOn field contains epoc time eg:"1548659664131"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a filter expression with 2 dates, you're probably looking for the BETWEEN statement.

> '#createdOn between :from and :to'

I suggest that you take a look at [this guide on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html) for using dynamodb with javascript.